# Array reference in a class error in php

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have this class which populates and prints an array

```
<?php

class testArray
{
    private $myArr;

    public function __construct() { 
        $myArr = array();
    }
    public static function PopulateArr() {

        $testA = new testArray();
        $testA->populateProtectedArr();
        return $testA;

    }
    protected function populateProtectedArr()
    {
        $this->myArr[0] = 'red'; 
        $this->myArr[1] = 'green'; 
        $this->myArr[2] = 'yellow';
        print_r ($this->myArr); 


    }
    public function printArr() {
        echo "<br> 2nd Array";
        print_r ($this->myArr);
    }
}
?>
```

I instantiate this class from another file and try to print the array in different function.

```
<?php
    require_once "testClass.php";


    $u = new testArray();
    $u->PopulateArr();
    $u->printArr();
?>
```

I am not able to print the array in the `printArr()` function. I want to get reference to the array that I had set the values in .

Comment: Your `populateProtectedArr()` needs to __return__ `$this->myArr`

Comment: public function __construct() { 
        $myArr = array();
    }  should become:
public function __construct() { 
        $this->myArr = array();
    }

Comment: `PopulateArr()` is defined `static`, but you're calling it as though it was an instance method

Comment: @MarkBaker you are wrong in both cases, no need to return anything, and also static methods can be called from objects too

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili - Then perhaps you'd interpret what the poster is trying to do, and explain why `PopulateArr()` is defined as static? As it is, I'd already given up trying to figure out the logic of this until you reminded me by telling me I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed one thing, you have to assign result of `$u->PopulateArr();` to `$u` again, otherwise you will not get the object you created from that method call, so:

```
$u = new testArray();
$u = $u->PopulateArr(); // this will work
$u->printArr();
```

This also can be done like this:

```
$u = testArray::PopulateArr();
$u->printArr();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `$u` object never populates the private array.

Instead you create a new object `$testA` and populate its array.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you understanding the way

```
class testArray
{
    private $myArr;

    public function __construct() { 
        $this->myArr = array();
    }
    public static function PopulateArr() {

        $testA = new testArray();
        $testA->populateProtectedArr();
        return $testA;

    }
    protected function populateProtectedArr()
    {
        $this->myArr[0] = 'red'; 
        $this->myArr[1] = 'green'; 
        $this->myArr[2] = 'yellow';
        return $this->myArr;
    }
    public function printArr() {
        echo "<br> 2nd Array";
        return $this->PopulateArr();
    }
}
```

**another.php**

```
require_once "testClass.php";
$u = new testArray();
print_r($u->PopulateArr());
print_r($u->printArr());
```

Here we are accessing the values of `protected function PopulateArr` instead of printing within function I just replaced it with `return` and print it over another file and within `printArr` function just call the `PopulateArr` function and that's it